# Why is rails changing my placeholder hashtag values?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have hyperlinks with href="#" that are assigned to client-side javascript event handlers.  When making requests via ajax, these links behave as expected (via "click" events) but when I occasionally use a link generated by the Rails link_to helper these href values suddenly become corrupted: href="#" becomes href="users/1/photo/4" for example.  Every link on the page picks up the same value!

When I use Chrome's Inspect Element, it reveals that the rendered href value remains href="#", yet rolling over it reveals it is pointed to the unwanted url.  The event listeners fail.  Is this turbolinks forcing my link placeholders to take on unwanted values?  Why is rails messing with my links?

Here is typical javascript code assigning an event handler:

```
Menu.prototype.activatePhotosLink = function() {
    var self = this;

    // ======= get all user photos =======
    $("#main-nav").on("click", function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        self.getUserPhotos();
    });
}
```

Here's how the link looks via Chrome's Inspect Element with href="#":

```
<a href="#" id="main-nav" data-no-turbolink="true">photos</a>
```

I tried to fix this problem with data-no-turbolink="true" but that did not work.  Meanwhile, here is what I see in the browser's "link to tooltips" on rollover:

```
localhost:30000/users/1#
```

Why not href="#"?  Thank you for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is not corrupted. It should be the path of the page you are at with the hashtag appended to it. This is not related to Rails nor JavaScript, but rather a feature in HTML. In HTML, if you want to create an anchor link to a certain element in the page, you pass its `id` to the `href`. You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

If you don't want a url to appear when you roll over the link, you can use `href='javascript:void(0)'`

Comment: You just saved me hours of effort.  Works as expected now.  Thank you!